# ansible 2.0.0-0.3.beta1 ec2_vpc_route_table ec2_vpc_subnet

Tags: ansible

I am creating an ansible playbook using version  2.0.0-0.3.beta1

I'd like to get the subnet id after i create a subnet. I'm refering the official ansible docs : http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_route_table_module.html

```
   - name: Create VPC Public Subnet
     ec2_vpc_subnet:
       state: present
       resource_tags: '{"Name":"{{ prefix }}_subnet_public_0"}'
       vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
       az: "{{ az0 }}"
       cidr: 172.16.0.0/24
     register: public

   - name: Create Public Subnet Route Table
     ec2_vpc_route_table:
       vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
       region: "{{ region }}"
       tags:
         Name: Public
       subnets:
         - "{{ public.subnet_id }}"
       routes:
         - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
         gateway_id: "{{ igw.gateway_id }}"
```

after running the playbook i received following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! 'dict object' has no attribute 'subnet_id'"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `public.subnet.id` instead of `public.subnet-id`

Its useful to debug by running this task:

```
- debug: msg="{{ public }}"
```

Comment: Yes, found it already, just i was curious why in the ansible docs they've showed the attribute as subnet_id instead of subnet.id